# How to fetch file from frontend to backend

Tags: reactjs, frontend, fetch, backend, multer

how to fetch file from frontend to backend ,
from backend using postman perfectly fine,  file is stored in upload folder using multer,
but i am not able to do from frontend, whats wrong with frontend side , where i am doing wrong while fetching

This is backend code working perfectly fine with the postman and thunder client

```
const express = require("express")
const fs = require("fs")
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' })

const fileRoutes = express.Router()



fileRoutes.post("/upload",upload.single("uploaded_file"),(req,res)=>{
    
    console.log(req.file,"file")
    // console.log(req.files,"files")
    // console.log(req.body,"body")
    fs.rename(`./uploads/${req.file.filename}`,`./uploads/${req.file.originalname}`,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log("renamed")
            res.send("image uploaded succesfully")
        }
    })
})

fileRoutes.get("/readall",(req,res)=>{
    try {
        console.log("readingall")
        
        let content = fs.readdirSync("./uploads").map(fileName => {
            return fileName;
          });

          res.send({msg:content})
    } catch (error) {
        res.send({msg:error})
    }
})


fileRoutes.get("/read",(req,res)=>{
    try {
        console.log("reading")
        
        const content = fs.readFileSync("./uploads/file.Routes.js",{encoding:"utf8"})
        res.send({msg:content})

    } catch (error) {
        res.send({msg:error})
    }
})

module.exports = {fileRoutes}
```

this is react code frontend

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

const FileUpload = () => {
    const [state,setState] = useState()


    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        // e.preventDefault()
        // console.log(e.target.files[0])
        setState(e.target.files[0])
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        // console.log(e.target.form)
        console.log(state)

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('File',state )
        console.log(formData,"formdata")

        fetch("http://localhost:8080/file/upload",{
            method:"POST",
            body: formData,
            // headers:{
            //     'Content-Type': "application/pdf",
            //     // 'content-length': `${state.size}`,
            // }
        })
        // .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res=>console.log(res))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))

    }

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Upload File</h1>

        {/* <div style={{margin:"auto", textAlign:'center'}}>
            <p>Upload a New file here</p>
            <input  type="file" onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)} name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" /><br />
            <button onClick={()=>handleSubmit()} >Submit</button>

        </div> */}

        <form    >
        <div >
            <input type="file" onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)} name="uploaded_file" />
            {/* <input type="submit" value="Submit" />             */}
        <button onClick={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
  )
}

export default FileUpload
```

Comment: What is getting logged here `.then(res=>console.log(res))` when you fetch from the client?

Comment: to check if the response is a success or failed

Comment: Yeah but **what** is being logged there when the request is performed, and also what do you mean by " i am not able to do from frontend", can you provide a more specific details on that? like a browser console error or maybe your application not working as expected after performing that call.